# CLFloor returns level 2146959360?

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit, cllocation

I’m using [`CLLocationManager`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager), looking at the [`location`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423687-location) property and examining the [`level`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clfloor/1616759-level) of the [`floor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1616762-floor), if any. The documentation suggests that if it couldn’t determine the `floor`, that it would just return `nil`. In practice, I am getting a `CLFloor` instance, but its `level` is 2146959360. Converting that to hex, 0x7FF80000, which looks suspiciously like some cryptic sentinel value.

```
lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    return locationManager
}()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
    case .notDetermined: locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    case .denied:        redirectToSettings()
    default:             break
    }
}

@IBAction func didTapGetLocation(_ sender: Any) {
    updateLabels(for: locationManager.location)
}

func updateLabels(for location: CLLocation?) {
    guard let location = location else {
        floorLabel.text = "No location."
        return
    }

    if let floor = location.floor {
        let hexString = "0x" + String(format: "%08x", floor.level)
        floorLabel.text = "\(floor.level) (\(hexString))"
    } else {
        floorLabel.text = "No floor."
    }
}
```

I’m seeing this behavior in on a physical iOS 13.3.1 devices, only. FWIW, older iOS versions (I’ve only got iOS 10 device sitting here) appear to return `nil`, as expected, as does the simulator.

What’s going on?

Comment: I agree that this is contrary to the documentation, but the value is not surprising. This is NSNotFound.

Comment: Is one running on a 32-bit platform (watch)? NSNotFound is now NSIntegerMax (back before 10.6, it was always 0x7fff..., but since 10.6 it's just been the max integer)

Comment: Nope, just iOS 13.3.1 on iPhone X (and Xs Max), using Xcode 11.3.1 (11C504). And the value is 0x7ff80000, not 0x7fffffff. But I guess it doesn’t matter where they got this value, as it ain’t right either way. It is curious, tho.

Comment: Still there in 13.4. Lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem goes away if you call [`startUpdatingLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423750-startupdatinglocation). If you do that, then the [`floor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1616762-floor) property will be `nil`. This `CLFloor` instance with a [`level`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clfloor/1616759-level) value of  2146959360 (0x7FF80000) only appears if you query the `location` of the `CLLocationManager` without having first called `startUpdatingLocation`.

The documentation suggests that this `location` property is populated with the last known value. Regardless, the `floor` should be `nil` (for my particular location, at least) but isn’t. The `level` is invalid.

See [this repo](https://github.com/robertmryan/CLFloorBug) for example of manifestation of the bug and demonstration of how calling `startUpdatingLocation` works.

[image]

I’ve filed a bug report (FB7638281).